# Error: response status is 404 Swagger, haciendo POST

Tags: c#, web, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, swagger

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo una web api con el modelo de arquitectura limpia, al momento de iniciar el swagger y tratar de probar los controllers, me marca el error 404, como se puede apreciar en la imagen, no se, si mi configuracion este mal, pero a lo que leí en ocasiones puede ser el cors, ya le anduve moviendo y no puedo hacer que funcione, alguien puede hecharme una mano?:(

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var Configuration = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IConfiguration>();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(Configuration);

builder.Services.AddDbContext(builder.Configuration)
    .AddDefaultConfigurations(builder.Configuration)
    .AddFilters()
    .AddServices();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
();

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseCors(builder => builder
       .AllowAnyHeader()
       .AllowAnyMethod()
       .AllowAnyOrigin()
    );
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();

app.Run();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

Olvide Mapearlos y se corregió